# Android studio's emulator is not connecting to internet

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I'm using windows 10 and android studio 3.0.1.
In past, I was able to use internet at my Android emulators but now, I'm not !
I saw similar topic in stackoverflow but answers not working for me, 
what should I do ?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling emulator.

Comment: I would install genymotion

Comment: newly created emulators are also having trouble ?

Comment: @Prashant Yes, I deleted all of the emulators and made new one, 
if you mean is this ?!

Comment: @SantanuSur yeah, unfortunately  :(

Comment: The issue may be due to the emulator tries to obtain its DNS settings from that LAN card(Assuming you are using wireless network). To solve this you have to Disable your LAN card.
Go to your Network connections, find your LAN card, right click it and  disable it.

Comment: yeas I think problem is because of DNS too but solution not working !  @Chandralal

Comment: I had my Windows 10 computer's DNS or name server settings set to 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1, ClouldFlare (with at&t internet service) I have to do 2 actions for my Android Emulator to connect to the internet, tested and confirmed using the chrome browser on Android Emulator. First action is the answer above from kali, [disabling proxy in Android Emulator setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DDnC.png), and second action is setting my Windows 10 computer DNS server to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 [windows 10 dns server settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5tU8.png)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally I found the answer! 
I'm using proxy in my android studio and emulators by default using android studio proxy setting too!
I just disabled proxy in emulator and problem solved!

Comment: Yup proxy connections does creates some truble

Comment: thank you @Prashant , your answer gave me the main idea :)

Comment: I also solved the issue by unchecking the "use android studio proxy settings" in the emulator settings. But I needed to restart the emulator too.

Answer (score 15):

try this command on windows cmd while replace the path with your own.

`C:\Users\prashant\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5X_API_25 -dns-server 8.8.8.8`

If this doesn't work try genymotion, it's best. [Here](https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone)

Comment: this worked ! thank you, what was the problem and how can I fix the problem for ever with out using cmd ?

Comment: glad to know that but @kali this is temporary solution and you have problem with your Internet connection settings you have to address that.

Comment: For mac, enter this in terminal: `./emulator -avd your_Avd_name -dns-server 8.8.8.8`

Answer (score 0):

you need to enable your internet conection to share with another conected devices, once you do it restart the emulator and you got internet

this works for windows

1. go to your conection properties
2. go to sharing tab
3. click in "Allow other network users to connect through this compueters connection

Answer (score 0):

This problem appeared out of nowhere for me after updating Android Studio to Chipmunk. After a great deal of searching and trying different solutions, I found one on Medium.com that solved it! This is a very similar fix that Prashant posted (setting the DNS server to 8.8.8.8), but it gave a step-by-step solution without using terminal, and included adding 8.8.4.4 as well.

[DNS fix for Windows or Mac](https://medium.com/@daydreamer_/how-to-fix-android-emulator-wi-fi-connected-with-no-internet-c62fd4ed652d)

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue and finally I realized the problem is because of my firewall (Kaspersky).

- Go to in firewall application settings and search 'Android studio'.
- You may find several applications with the same name, allow all of them to access Internet.
- For me, there were 2 apps including JetBrains extension, which i had blocked long time ago!